# Howto bind SpringBoot with SpringData to Elasticsearch in CloudFoundry?

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

When starting Elasticsearch locally on my development machine I can connect from SpringBoot to Elasticsearch and my JUnit testcases works.

But when I try to connect to Cloud Foundry Elasticsearch it does not work.

Starting on command line, i.e. redirecting port 9300 to Cloud Foundry:

```
cf ssh -N -L 9300:8twkrqe7blbjoi28.service.consul:47289 my-proxy
```

I use the same port and configuration in SpringBoot for both local Elasticsearch and with Cloud Foundry Elasticsearch:

```
public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {

@Bean
public Client client() throws Exception {
    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
        .put("spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes", "localhost:9300")
        .build();

    TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder()
        .settings(settings)
        .build()
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
    return client;
}

@Bean
public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
}
```

Running my JUnit testcases I get the following error when trying to save towards ElasticsearchRepository with Cloud Foundry:

```
Caused by: NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:326)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:223)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:295)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:359)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:348)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.execute(AbstractClient.java:1221)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.exists(AbstractClient.java:1241)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.indexExists(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:622)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.deleteIndex(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:639)
at ch.stockscan.config.elasticsearch.IndexReinitializer.resetIndex(IndexReinitializer.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
```

From Postman I can do a GET from my local machine and I get result from Cloud Foundry:

```
http://localhost:9300/_cat/indices?v
```

Output:

```
  health status index               pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
    yellow open   parsed-2018.02.07     5   1        177            0      343kb          343kb 
    yellow open   parsed-2018.02.08     5   1        196            0    503.2kb        503.2kb 
    yellow open   .kibana               1   1          4            0     16.7kb         16.7kb 
...
```

Im not sure why this is not working from SpringBoot with Cloud Foundry?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to ElastiSearch to read / write event logs? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Im saving a @Document(indexName = "mydata" public class MyData {...} with ElasticsearchRepository interface via Spring Data.

Comment: If I understand, you are using ElastiSearch as a service. Assuming ElastiSearch is running outside of CF, use CUPS to inject it to the foundation. Create a service instance and bind it to your app.  Just like you will do for Oracle or any other external service.

Comment: Elasticsearch and Kibana run in Cloud in Cloud Foundry as a Service. Please answer with a detailed explanation. Thanks!

Comment: If you have deployed ElastiSearch and Kibana as a tile, you should see those services when you run `cf marketplace`. Do you see any services for those?

Comment: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/managing-services.html

Comment: Yes I see ELK as a Service. But that does not help me, please read my question again.

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not working for you, in your bean definition, it is pointing to localhost, which in cloud foundry has no meaning.

Create a service instance (`cf create-service --help`). Then bind that service instance to a sample app, and look at env properties (`cf env`). That should give you the name of the key.

Then modify your code, set a property as follows...

> @Value("${vcap.services.elastisearch.url:http://localhost:9300}")
>   private String elastisearchEndpoint;

and use that, instead of hardcoding localhost.

Here are few links for reference:

- https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-value-default-value/
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/cloud/CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.html
- https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html

The other option is to have two different implementations of your bean. One in  `LocalConfig` for **@profile="default"** and `CloudConfig` for **@profile="cloud"**.

Apps run in Cloud Foundry under `cloud` profile.

Comment: Thanks, I will study you answer tomorrow. I improved my question a bit, small point: I redirect port 9300 to Cloud Foundry on my localhost. Postman works from my localhost, but not SpringBoot is working or seems to understand the redirected localhost port. This is also just a first step to see if it works with versions from Elasticsearch and Spring Data. Then I have to provide a proper configuration when I finally deploy my new SpringBoot ready Elasticsearch application for real to CloudFoundry.

Comment: Sorry Im not able to configure my SpringBoot towards Cloud Foundry with this information, it's to vague.

Comment: Have you ever ran [Spring Music](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/spring-music) on cloud foundry? If not, go thru it. It has step by step guide on how you can run locally, and in the cloud. There are instructions on how to create a service instance and bind it.